# Dynamic variables within SQL

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Good morning guys,

I'm having a slight issue with a SQL stored procedure. I am posting these variables to the procedure via. a HTML form:

```
Post Params:
key: 'DocID_1' value: '18743921-3810-4516-AA6B-566DF1045BDE'
key: 'status_1' value: 'Ignore'
key: 'DocID_2' value: '228C53F6-FE71-4816-8865-B52C02114D54'
key: 'status_2' value: 'Ignore'
key: 'DocID_3' value: 'ABCFCD74-56A3-4B11-B2C4-8D5B827E5648'
key: 'status_3' value: 'Ignore'
key: 'DocID_4' value: 'CD3F7440-BC71-48D0-B358-9EA5366ACCDE'
key: 'status_4' value: 'Ignore'
key: 'rowCount' value: '4'
```

Which are basically a list of documents which need to be approved, ignored etc. In my stored procedure I've got a function which iterates up to the `rowCount` variables value. What I am trying to do is use a `select` statement to select each `DocID_` passed to the procedure.

My `select` statement so far:

```
DECLARE @rowCount int = 4
DECLARE @DocID_1 nvarchar(80) = '18743921-3810-4516-AA6B-566DF1045BDE'

SELECT 
    num,
    @DocID_ + num
FROM 
    dbo.ufn_getcount(1, @rowCount)
```

As you can see I am trying to concatenate `@DocID_` and `num`, which is the number returned by my function. This returns an error which to be honest I expected:

`Must declare the scalar variable "@DocID_"`

After reviewing the above, is there any way to dynamically create variable names on the fly?

Comment: @lad2025 Sorry? I am trying to dynamically create the variable name within the select statement according to the `rowCount` variable, it is not a case of missing the `1`.

Comment: What do you mean dynamic variables? Are you confusing them with table variables perhaps? And why do you expect adding two variables to result in a new variable call instead of returning the concatenation or addition result fo these two variables?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `This returns an error which to be honest I expected`. I knew this would error, and I know the variable values would concatenate. I am looking to create variable names on the fly.

Comment: You'll need to build your entire SQL string dynamically and execute it, if you want to be able to use dynamic variables inside it.

Comment: SQL is not one of the languages where you can create variable names on the fly. Perhaps there are some dynamic languages that allow this? One reason may be that this sounds like an excelent vector for SQL injection attacks

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen that would be an awful idea, making injection attacks a lot easier, while requiring more keystrokes than just addressing the variables individually. Or passing a table-valued parameter.

Comment: @MikeResoli *why* do you want to use the variables in this way? Why not simply use them individually? What do you expect to gain? Why not create a table parameter with (ID,status) fields and add the rows you want to it?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Dynamic SQL is as injection safe as static, if you write it properly. Dynamic SQL have plenty of benefits - enabling you to make optimized and exact smaller queries compared to larger "one-size-fits-all" or a vast number queries.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen comparing a faulty practice to other bad practices doesn't make it a good one. Writing a one-size-fits-all is a bad practice, while a "vast" number of queries simpley doesn't exist - the *optimizer* will deal with the final result, whether that comes from concatenation or direct submission of the same text. The same number of execution plans will get generated in both cases. Debugging of the "dynamic sql" though will be a *lot* harder

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what the advantage of selecting @DocID_ + num (were that a valid operation) would be - from the code sample you've listed you'd seem likely to know which variable was being selected anyway?

This *could* be done with dynamic SQL but it wouldn't be simple and the possibility for SQL Injection if it wasn't properly constructed is significant. Instead I'd look at the underlying requirement and work out how better to implement it. Possible options -

- Table valued parameters
- Table variables / temporary tables
- Amending your getcount function to return the value you're specifically looking for - we'd need to see it's code to be certain but I suspect it'd be possible.